# Can the nameservers point to 2 different providers?

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, dns, gmail

We are in the process of moving our emails over to Office365, they are currently stored in Gmail.

The concern we have is that between the different employees and timezones, if we change the nameservers at once to Microsoft's, then if it takes 48 hours for some employees to update their mailbox, they won't be receiving emails in between when we change the nameservers and when they update their email account.

So, can I add the name servers that Microsoft recommend to the domain, and have *my* email account active under Microsoft, while someone else's email (same domain) is still working under Gmail?

Answer (score 2):

No.

In order to manage this change you need to get someone with appropriate knowledge, otherwise you are in for a world of hurt.

In brief, you need to prepare for the change by reducing the TTL for mail records.   If your domain is competently set up you will also  need to modify records like SPF.

Once you have swapped, you then test and again modify the TTL.

Note that this is only a broad overview, exact steps (and possible extra steps like using a proxy or multiple MX records for backups) have been ignored.

***Reasons why what you are asking about won't work***

- DNS caches responses.  Thus even with 1 set of nameservers you will have issues.
- (In general for mail clients), the nameserver selected from the available list at random.  Even if you can control this for your staff, you can't control it (other then by programming it correctly and using low TTL values ) for all mail servers.
- DNS works at a per domain level - not a per email address/account level.

Comment: +1 for "a world of hurt" ;)

Comment: Hmm, thanks for the comment. So,despite being generally tech savvy - would you recommend to outsource this work to someone else to avoid potential issues if misconfigured?

I have successfully migrated 1 domain + email as a test over to Microsoft, and despite losing some old emails (in the future will back up emails in future, but in this case I wasn't worried about losing emails). This gives me a little bit of confidence, although I am aware that running into any DNS conflicts may be when things start to get chaotic, as I haven't dealt with these problems before.

Comment: I'M HOME based on your question, If you worked with me I'd say you are not ready to do this. If the entity can afford to loose emails for a few days and money is tight, its a learning exercise - if its important to have minimal disruption you really need someone with more skill.

Comment: If you do go it yourself, make sure you set the DNE  TTLs low before the cutover so you can more quickly respond to issues/mistakes.